# ERROR: mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

I started getting this error whenever I restart my OS. I tried to erase and install Ubuntu Linux again and the installation freezes at "Running update-grub". Not sure if those two things are related.

I have a lenovo G500 and I run Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version on it.

Let me know if you need more details.

[image]

[image]

Comment: From those error messages, you have a dying main hard disk or SSD. I recommend that you replace it ASAP.

Comment: Also see this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443090/mdadm-no-arrays-found-in-config-file-or-automatically

Answer (score 1):

I think this message comes when you don't have hard disk arrays. While booting, mdadm checks for arrays and don't find any. So this message is annoying, but harmless.