# mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically

Tags: boot, external-hdd, mdadm

On a 22.04.1 Ubuntu HP EliteBook 8570w laptop the following message is displayed a number of times when I boot it without an external disk (two partitions, data not system) plugged in:

```
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

And in the middle of these messages, one line indicating:

```
mdadm: error opening /dev/md?*: No such file or directory
```

There's no RAID at all on this machine, and apart it takes slightly longer to boot, I see no difference when booted.

I'd like to find the way to solve this in order to accelerate a bit the boot sequence when I don't have this external drive plugged in.

I added theses lines in /etc/mdadm/dmadm.conf, followed by update-initramfs -u

```
ARRAY <ignore> devices=/dev/sda
ARRAY <ignore> devices=/dev/sdb
ARRAY <ignore> devices=/dev/sdc
ARRAY <ignore> devices=/dev/sdd
ARRAY <ignore> devices=/dev/sde
ARRAY <ignore> devices=/dev/sdf
```

And I also switched AHCI to IDE in the BIOS for no difference (regarding this topic).

Any advice?

Comment: I have the same issue. It is not unique to Ubuntu; Debian can have it as well: https://serverfault.com/questions/1043282/how-is-mdadm-stopped-from-doing-an-auto-scan-at-startup

This fix did not help me, FWIW.

Comment: If you have a HDD, set it to IDE. But if you have a SSD, set it to AHCI.

Comment: I have a SSD. The BIOS setting is already set to AHCI.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue. I found the answer at

[Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224114/gave-up-waiting-for-suspend-resume-device)

The answer for me was to run
sudo update-initramfs -u

Comment: Had exact same issue as OP on Debian 12, and `sudo update-initramfs -u` fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My own solution was to add `noresume` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` and run `sudo update-grub`.

I also removed the `mdadm` package, but I am not sure that this is needed with the `noresume` option.